# Как правильно сказать: в первый год работы или на первом году работы?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно сказать: в первый год работы или на первом году работы? Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Второй вариант возможен только в редких случаях, когда речь идёт об однократном событии в пределах обозначенного периода, скорее всего, не связанном с "работой" (сломал ногу, женился и т. п.); не исключено даже, что работа в тот момент прервалась и год был неполным, если не оказался первым и последним. Первый же вариант ("в первый год работы") подходит практически к любому контексту, особенно, связанному с содержанием работы (напр. "занялся диссертацией").